# Change onmouseover="this.src='xxx'" when item is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onmouseover, onmouseclick

I have this image which on hover changes the src:

```
<img id="apripreventivo" src="img.svg" onmouseover="this.src='img_hover.svg'" onmouseout="this.src='img.svg'">
```

Then I have a script that when that image is clicked toggles a div (*#contact-form*):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $("#contact-form").hide();
        $("#apripreventivo").show();

    $('#apripreventivo').click(function(){
    $("#contact-form").slideToggle();
    });

});
```

How can I rewrite the above function to also have that when the image (*#apripreventivo*) is clicked, its `onmouseover` src changes to e.g. *img_hover2.svg* ("normal" src and `onmouseout` be the same. And still *#contact-form*" div toggling on click). Then when clicked again the `onmouseover` should return to original (*img_hover.svg*).

Comment: Of what? There's an image which changes src="" when on hover. Same image when clicked toggles a div. What I want is that when has been clicked (so div is toggled) the on hover img src to be changed. When the image is clicked again (and div untoggled), the on hover img src to return to the "original".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've gotten you most of the way: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andRyanMiller/vpgV8/2/).

The trick is simply to change the attribute of the img tag using jQuery's $.attr() method.

```
$('img').click(function() {
    $(this).attr("onmouseover", "this.src='http://newevolutiondesigns.com/images/freebies/cat-wallpaper-7.jpg'");
})
```

You can easily write a function which checks the current value of this attribute, then sets the correct value on click. Hope this helps!

Comment: Close! But when clicking the image again the onmouseover src doesn't return the "original".

Comment: Sorry for the rush. :)

Comment: I'm waiting just a little bit to see if there are other answers but in the meanwhile thanks!! :))